# Eliminate character after reading with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am printing some values from a file using `awk`

`awk 'NR>1{print $20,$45,$102}' RS='vector'`

it prints them fine, but unfortunately a value is always printed as it is,i.e. together with `:`

```
1 8: 34  
1 9: 32
```

Is there a way of removing `:` after the value, so I could get:

```
1 8 34  
1 9 32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the printf function to format it as a number:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%d %d %d\n", $20,$45,$102}' RS='vector'
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess the `:` belongs to the column 45. You could remove it with awk's `sub()` function.

try this:

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/:$/,"",$45); print $20,$45,$102}' RS='vector' file
```

Comment: Good one. Also `$45+0` can make it. By the way, did you have a [baby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2611798/junior-d)? :D

Comment: @fedorqui I thought of `+0` too. However when I read the question twice, I just see "value(s)", instead of "number(s)". therefore I went with `sub()`, I thought it would be more generic. Sure, if OP wanted only numbers to be printed, `+0 or *1` would be a nice short-cut. and FYI, I don't have the baby. :) he is obviously a Debian guy. And I have Arch in heart! :D

Answer (score 5):

You didn't show your input file so it's guess-work but maybe all you need is to include the `:` in your FS:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $20,$45,$102}' FS='[[:space:]:]+' RS='vector'
```